# jquery script doesnt work when I change the folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have header.html and footer.html in root .my main page is in the folder "MainPages".I use script to call header.html and footer.html.
but I can not see Header.html and footer.html when I double click on the the page .
here is my folders and my Mainpage("bio.html")(bio.html is in the MainPages"folder).
[image: project folders]

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="../Content/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="../Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/revealOnscroll.js"></script>
    <link href="../Content/ava.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#Header").load("../Header.html");
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#Footer").load("../Footer.html");
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body style="background-image: url(../images/sample_bg.jpg);">

    <!--header-part-->
    <div id="Header"></div>

    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

    <div class=" container-fluid col-md-offset-2 row col-md-8 col-md-offset-2  "
         style=" font-family: Mitra;background-image:url(../images/bio/bio-2.jpg);background-size:500px,500px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position-x:right;background-position-y:top;
            background-color:#fff ;clear:none;padding: 0px;">
        <div class="container-fluid ">
            <div class="row ">


                <div class=" col-md-offset-1 col-md-9 ">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="bio-contex-1">

                            <span>

                                this is my main page for testing
                            </span>

                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <br />
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!--footer-->

    <div id="Footer"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to convert ./../header.html

Comment: also check console is there any error

Comment: I do not see any issue with your code. Are you using any localserver.

Comment: yes I run it local.

Comment: ./../header.html  does not work too.

Comment: when bio.html is in the root it works well ,but when I change the folder it doesnt work.

Comment: Do you have extensions hidden in the Explorer? Do yourself a favor and enable the display of extensions. Windows can throw .htm and .html files together if it wants and then you won't be able to distinguish between them.

Comment: sorry , what is prose!

Comment: So the whole folder is mounted on the webserver? You are accessing your bio.html like this: `localhost/MainPages/bio.html` ?

Comment: file:///D:/web/MainPages/bio.html

Comment: use as `$("#Header").load("/../Header.html");`

Comment: no,it does not work.

Comment: i think this is not some proper method as `$(function(){` should use `$("#Header").load("../Header.html");` or in `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: @mndn i dont think `$(...).load()` will work from local file system. You need to use a local webserver to serve your files. Try something like XAMPP or Fenix.

Comment: i think, you copy and paste your `folder`, then you copy your `script` files from different `folders` so the `path` should not be  connected `(inside your script)`. try it should solve..

Comment: It works when I use Visual studio,But I want to use it without visual .do you think it does not work locally?

Comment: You might need check you console, you getting any errors ?

Comment: there is no error,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run a local webserver, as you might be getting problems loading file in jquery under`file:///`

Set up a webserver and then try to load them again.

Use npm : [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

Answer (score 0):

change ../  to /

e.g

```
  <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: also change same in $("#Header").load("../Header.html"); to $("#Header").load("/Header.html");

Comment: no,it does not work and  change the view in bad way.